# Excel - Duplicate rows based on contents of a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with 600 rows. Each row represents between 2 and 12 geographic features, each with their own reference number or 'NGR'.

I want each row to only represent one feature however. So if a row had 3 features in it, I'd want 3 copies of the row with only the 'NGR' reference number changed.

In summary I want this:

How it is now
[image]

Changed to this:

How I want it
[image]

Notice how the rows are duplicated but the NGR column keeps the unique reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Power Query` -- a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 or later; and built-in to Excel 2016 / Office 365 where it is called `Get & Transform`  You merely (in Excel 2016; steps probably similar in 2010)

- Select `Get&Transform` from `Table/Range`
- In the Power Query Editor, select the NGR column

  - Split by delimiter (comma)
- Then select the split columns (there will be three or maybe more)
- Unpivot those columns

Results using your data:

[image]

- Delete the new column labelled `Attribute`
- Move the column with the NGR values back to the beginning and rename the column.

When you have new data, you can always rerun the query to peform the same operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a button click control and assign the macro:

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    arr = Sheets(1).UsedRange
    a = 2
    For j = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If InStr(arr(j, 1), ",") > 0 Then
            brr = Split(arr(j, 1), ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(brr)
                Cells(a, 1) = brr(i)
                For k = 2 To 4
                    Cells(a, k) = arr(j, k)
                Next k
                a = a + 1
            Next i
        Else
            For i = 1 To 4
                Cells(a, i) = arr(j, i)
            Next i
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next j
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this script and run ***DuplicateLine*** sub

```
Function getLastCell(pChamp As String)

    Dim LastColonne As Double
    Dim LastLigne As Double
    Dim vCurrentCell

    vCurrentCell = ActiveCell.Address

    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    LastColonne = ActiveCell.Column
    LastColonne = LastColonne

    LastLigne = ActiveCell.Row
    LastLigne = LastLigne

    Range(vCurrentCell).Select

    If pChamp = "LINE" Then
        getLastCell = LastLigne
    ElseIf pChamp = "COLUMN" Then
        getLastCell = LastColonne
    Else
        getLastCell = "ERROR : Param LINE / COLUMN"
    End If


End Function

Function CutLine(pLine As Variant, pSeparator As String)
    Dim fields As Variant
    Dim vLine As Variant

    fields = Array()
    i = 0
    pos = 1
    vLine = pLine
    Do While pos <> 0
        pos = InStr(vLine, pSeparator)
        ReDim Preserve fields(i)
        If pos <> 0 Then
            fields(i) = Left(vLine, pos - 1)
            vLine = Mid(vLine, pos + Len(pSeparator))
        Else
            fields(i) = vLine
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    CutLine = fields
End Function

Function getElement(pString As String, pSeparator As String, pId As Double)

    vTab = CutLine(pString, pSeparator)

    getElement = vTab(pId - 1)
    'getElement = vTab(0)

End Function

Function getNbElement(pString As String, pSeparator As String)

    vTab = CutLine(pString, pSeparator)

    getNbElement = UBound(vTab) + 1

End Function

Function getLastElement(pString As String, pSeparator As String)

    vTab = CutLine(pString, pSeparator)

    getLastElement = vTab(UBound(vTab))

End Function

Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber As Double) As String


    If ColumnNumber <= 0 Then
        'negative column number
        ColumnLetter = ""

    ElseIf ColumnNumber > 16384 Then
        'column not supported (too big) in Excel 2007
        ColumnLetter = ""

    ElseIf ColumnNumber > 702 Then
        ' triple letter columns
        ColumnLetter = _
        Chr((Int((ColumnNumber - 1 - 26 - 676) / 676)) Mod 676 + 65) & _
        Chr((Int((ColumnNumber - 1 - 26) / 26) Mod 26) + 65) & _
        Chr(((ColumnNumber - 1) Mod 26) + 65)

    ElseIf ColumnNumber > 26 Then
        ' double letter columns
        ColumnLetter = Chr(Int((ColumnNumber - 1) / 26) + 64) & _
                Chr(((ColumnNumber - 1) Mod 26) + 65)
    Else
        ' single letter columns
        ColumnLetter = Chr(ColumnNumber + 64)

    End If

End Function


Sub DuplicateLine()
Dim j As Double


    vMaxLigne = getLastCell("LINE")
    vNewLineId = vMaxLigne + 1
    For i = 2 To vMaxLigne
        vNbSite = Cells(i, 3)
        If vNbSite <> "" Then 'Manage Null Rows

            If vNbSite > 1 Then
                For j = 1 To vNbSite
                    'Copy Original Line
                    Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
                    'Insert Original Line in New Line
                    Rows(vNewLineId & ":" & vNewLineId).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    vNgr = getElement(Cells(i, 2), ", ", j)
                    Range("B" & vNewLineId).Value = vNgr

                    vNewLineId = vNewLineId + 1
                Next j
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    'Delete Original Line
    Rows(2 & ":" & vMaxLigne).Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain how it works?